# Insert current date and time using Jess in ontology

Tags: java, jess

I am trying to link an individual in my ontology with the current date and time value with the following JessTab code:

```
(slot-insert$ TimeInstant_1 http://www.w3.org/2006/time#inXSDDateTime 1 (new Date))
```

But it returns the Java date object:

```
(<Java-Object:java.util.Date>)
```

And does not give the individual the current datetime value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `toString()` method to get the value of date. For example: `((new Date) toString)`.

Comment: Then you need to use `DateFormat` class in java. See http://herzberg.ca.sandia.gov/docs/70/java.html for more information.

Comment: :) I knew that approach i.e. integrating in Java. I thought if there might be any solution from Jess. Thanks anyway